Prohibition from having intimacy while being a guest - source from Chumash
I’m looking for a source from Chumash that intimacy should not be conducted in a another’s house.
I recently learned Siman 240:13 in OC Shulchan Aruch which prohibits intimacy when sleeping in another’s house. All the sources from there quote Ketubot 65a and the pasuk from Shmuel to prove it.
However, I explicitly remember learning the same idea from somewhere in Chumash, where a verse subtly indicates that a married couple (I forgot which one) remained separate. We learn from there good conduct in that they did not engage in intimacy while staying at someone else’s house.
If anyone can give me any relevant information, I would really appreciate it.
Thank you!

Rashi (Bereishis 12:2) says:

ואעשך לגוי גדול. לְפִי שֶׁהַדֶּרֶךְ גּוֹרֶמֶת לִשְׁלֹשָׁה דְבָרִים, מְמַעֶטֶת פְּרִיָּה וּרְבִיָּה וּמְמַעֶטֶת אֶת הַמָּמוֹן וּמְמַעֶטֶת אֶת הַשֵּׁם, לְכָךְ הֻזְקַק לִשְׁלֹשָׁה בְּרָכוֹת הַלָּלוּ, שֶׁהִבְטִיחוֹ עַל הַבָּנִים וְעַל הַמָּמוֹן וְעַל הַשֵּׁם:
AND I WILL MAKE OF THEE A GREAT NATION: Since traveling is the cause of three things — it decreases family life, it reduces one’s wealth and lessens one’s renown, he therefore needed these three blessings: that God should promise him children, wealth and a great name (Genesis Rabbah 39:11).

The Maharsha in Kesubos (65a) states that the reason traveling decreases family life is because intimacy is forbidden when one is a guest.

Genesis 26:8
Isaac engaged in intimacy (or at least behavior associated with man and wife and not done between brother and sister) when he was staying in Gerar, outside the king's palace.
This shows that the Avot were not concerned about intimacy while a guest.

They were "guests"in the kingdom to some degree, but were they not living there semi-permantently?
